# Issue with placing Tkinter widgets within frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've just started using Tkinter, and I'm having a very simple issue that is driving me insane. I'm trying to place a button within a label frame. It's a very simple task with many tutorials online. Simply create the button and assign the frame as the parent. Then use the pack command to pack the widget within its parent. However, when I do this the button - or any widget - is always under the parent. No matter whether I use pack or grid, the child widget is always beneath it. [Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UTba.png)

```
from tkinter import *

application = Tk()
lblframe = LabelFrame(application, width=300, height=300, text="Test", bd=10).pack()
btn = Button(lblframe, text="Button 1").pack()
application.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by `pack()` is None. So you are assigning `lblframe` to hold a value of None and therefore when you create the Button widget it has None passed as the parent. That causes its parent to be the application toplevel hence the packing you see (both widgets are packed into the same container). If you do the creation and packing separately it will work as you expect eg:

```
from tkinter import *

application = Tk()
lblframe = LabelFrame(application, width=300, height=300, text="Test", bd=10)
btn = Button(lblframe, text="Button 1")
lblframe.pack()
btn.pack()
application.mainloop()
```