# Tkinter: Placing a widget in a frame actually places it in root

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

So I have a unique problem that occurs on Windows (python 3.8.5) and Linux (python 3.8.2). When I place a widget in a certain Frame, it actually places in Root instead for whatever reason.

I'm using the [TkinterExtensions](https://pypi.org/project/TkinterExtensions/) library. I've looked at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572382/9530917) but it didn't help. I get the issue no matter what I do, but only for the one frame. I'm suspecting at this point it may be a Tkinter library bug.

EDIT: It seems to only happen in python 3.8.x. I tried it on another pc with 3.7.x and it works as expected.

Below is a very generic example.

```
from TkinterExtensions import *

class Root(tk.Tk):
    # sets up Tkinter and creates the other windows and places them accordingly.
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w1 = Window1(root=self).place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=1.0, relwidth=1.0)
        self.w2 = Window2(root=self).place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=1.0, relwidth=1.0)
        self.w3 = Window3(root=self).place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=1.0, relwidth=1.0)
        
        self.w1.hide()
        self.w2.hide()
        self.w3.hide()

class Window1(TkinterFrame):
    # ... anything needed for this frame
    # This is the frame that's causing the issue.
    # Despite the same code on all three windows, 
    # this one puts any widgets into root instead of as a child of this frame.
    
    def __init__(self, root)
        super().__init__(root)
        self.button = TkinterButton(master=self, Text="button").place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=1.0, relwidth=1.0)
    
class Window2(TkinterFrame):
    # ... anything needed for this frame
    # this frame works fine
    
class Window3(TkinterFrame):
    # ... anything needed for this frame
    # this frame works fine
```

I can create a repository if needed, with more extensive generic code.

Also, I'm the author of the [TkinterExtensions](https://pypi.org/project/TkinterExtensions/) library.

Comment: We don't need a repository, but we do need a [mcve].

Comment: Did you mean that the button created inside `Window1` is put in root?  How do you known that it is put in root?  Also your generic example has a very popular mistake: chain widget creation with `place()`, like `self.button = TkinterButton(...).place(...)`, which makes `self.button` to be `None`.  Also did you test the same example by changing all widgets from `TkinterExtensions` to normal `tkinter` widgets and see whether same issue occurs?

Comment: @acw1668 The TkinterExtensions library fixes that by returning self, so not true. Yes, i changed them all back as well.

Comment: It seems to only happen in python 3.8.x. I tried it on another pc with 3.7.x and it works as expected.

Comment: I tried your generic example (after fixing some syntax error and adding required code to make it runnable), it works in my Python 3.8.5 in Windows 7.  [Here](https://pastebin.com/NFwntMq3) is the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular frame, I have defined the **len** method. As soon as a renamed it, the layout manager, and any widgets placed in it, worked as expected. The Tkinter.Frame class doesn't define **len** so I don't know why it's causing an issue, but it did.